# How to disable tinyMCE button added by a plugin?

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I know how to disable `TinyMCE` default buttons with `add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init')` using `theme_advanced_disable` parameter, but a button added by a 3rd party plugin seems impossible to hide with `tiny_mce_before_init`

The available array with `add_filter('mce_buttons')` returns only the default tinyMCE buttons.

How to disable this tinyMCE button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that you can manual set availability button by this attribute `theme_advanced_buttons1` (for button in row 1)

Example :

```
function disable_mce_buttons( $opt ) {
    //set button that will be show in row 1
    $opt['theme_advanced_buttons1'] = 'bold,italic,strikethrough,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,link,unlink,wp_more,|,spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv,separator';
    return $opt;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'disable_mce_buttons');
```